# How to include moment.js for Tempus Dominus Bootstrap with requirejs in a Moodle plugin?

Tags: requirejs, moodle

Hello I am developping a Moodle plugin in which I need datetimepicker from Tempus Dominus Bootstrap

I used AMD requirejs.

In amd/src/ I have config.js:

```
define([], function () {
  window.requirejs.config({

    paths: {
        "moment": M.cfg.wwwroot + '/admin/tool/myplugin/js/moment.min',
        "bootstrap": M.cfg.wwwroot + '/admin/tool/myplugin/js/bootstrap.bundle.min',
        "datepicker": M.cfg.wwwroot + '/admin/tool/myplugin/js/bootstrap-datepicker141.min',
        "datetimepicker": M.cfg.wwwroot + '/admin/tool/myplugin/js/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min',

    },
    shim: {            
        'moment': {exports: 'moment'},
        'bootstrap': {exports: 'Bootstrap'},
        'datepicker': { exports: 'datepicker'}, 
        'datetimepicker': {deps: ['moment'], exports: '$.fn.datetimepicker'},
    }
});
});
```

datetimepicker.js:

```
define(['tool_myplugin/config', 'datetimepicker'], function(unused,datetimepicker) {
    return datetimepicker;
}
);
```

tool_myplugin.js:

```
define([
'jquery',
'tool_myplugin/moment',
'tool_myplugin/datepicker', 
'tool_myplugin/datetimepicker',
],
function ($,moment) {

    function initManage() {
        $(document).ready(() => {

        $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
            format: 'HH:mm',
            use24hours: true,
            defaultDate: moment({hour: 9, minute: 00})

        });
     });

    }
return {
    init: function () {
        initManage();

}
};
});
```

I have these errors in the console:

```
Error: Tempus Dominus Bootstrap4's requires moment.js. Moment.js must be included before Tempus Dominus Bootstrap4's JavaScript. tempusdominus-    bootstrap-4.min.js:20:9
.../tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.js:20:9
```

and

```
Error: No define call for datetimepicker
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#nodefine
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution:

here is amd/src/moment.js

```
define(['tool_myplugin/config',  'moment'], function(unused,moment) {

 window.moment = moment;
    if (!window.moment) {
        alert("moment ko");
    }
    return moment;
 }
);
```